# How can I get non-italic greek characters in a title/label (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to get non-italic greek characters into my matplotlib titles and labels, for example μ. I have so far written greek characters as follows:

```
plt.title('$\mu$)
```

This would print an italic mu. Now hoping to get it to be non-italic, I have tried to do:

```
plt.title('$\mathrm{\mu}$')
```

Sadly this does not change it at all, even though using \mathrm does work for normal characters. For example `plt.title('$\mathrm{test}$')` correctly prints 'test' in a non-italic font.

Why is this behaviour different for greek characters, and how do I fix this? I have googled and found more questions on this problem, but I couldn't get a clear answer on why \mathrm does not work and how I can solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also use unicode characters. As in `plt.title('μ')`. You can google 'mu unicode' and copy-paste the character into your editor. The same goes for other mathematical symbols you would like to use. Such as `≤`, `∈` or `≠`. See for example [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_operators/list.htm)

Comment: I had already tried this, but in the plot it would only show one of those little boxes you get one a character is not recognized (sorry, don't know the name for it).

Comment: Did you upgrade to Python3.8 and matplotlib 3.1.3 ?

Comment: I am using Python2.7 and matplotlib 2.1. I am working on a remote server, where I can sadly not use Python 3.

Comment: With Python 2 one could do `plt.title(u'μ')`. See Python 2's [unicode support](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a TeX font issue rather than a Python issue. The best solution for you is to use change the latex rc config for matplotlib like below

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['mathtext.default'] = 'regular'
```

Or in case you need italics in some parts just add `\it` before a text or a symbol.